# Integrate Moodle with multiple Bigbluebutton server

Tags: server, integration, moodle, bigbluebutton

Is it possible to integrate Moodle with multiple Bigbluebutton server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin can be found [here](https://moodle.org/plugins/mod_bigbluebuttonbn).
Since it is a mod, every instance in the course can be modified separately, so you may use every new instance with different BBB server.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.